# Parachuting and Air Resistance Modeled With Differential Equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A parachutist whose mass is  65 kg drops from a helicopter hovering 2500 m above the ground and falls toward the ground under the influence of gravity. Assume that the force due to air resistance is proportional to the velocity of the​ parachutist, with the proportionality constant $b_1$= 20 ​N-sec/m when the chute is closed and  ​$b_2$= 90 N-sec/m when the chute is open. If the chute does not open until the velocity of the parachutist reaches 25 ​m/sec, after how many seconds will the parachutist reach the​ ground? Assume that the acceleration due to gravity is $9.81 m/s^2$.

The answer is apparently 345.06 seconds.

In my work, the subscripts 1 and 2 represent the quantities they are attached to before and after the chute is opened, respectively. Can someone point out where I went wrong?

$$\sum F_{1}=mg-b_1v_1=m\frac{dv_1}{dt}$$

$$\frac{dv_1}{dt}=g-\frac{b_1}{m}v_1;\frac{b_1}{m}=c_1=\frac{4}{13}$$

$$\int_{0}^{v}\frac{dv_1}{g-c_1v_1}=\int_{o}^{t_1}dt;c_1=\frac{b_1}{m}\Rightarrow -\frac{ln(g-c_1v_1)}{c_1}=-\frac{ln(g-c_1v_1)}{c_1}+\frac{ln(g)}{c_1}=t_1$$

$$ln(\frac{g}{g-c_1v_1})=c_1t\Rightarrow e^{c_1t}=\frac{g}{g-c_1v_1}\Rightarrow v_1=-\frac{g}{c_1e^{c_1t}}+\frac{g}{c_1}=-\frac{9.81}{\frac{4}{13}e^{\frac{4}{13}t}}+\frac{9.81}{\frac{4}{13}}$$

$$v_1(t)=\frac{dx_1}{dt}=-31.885e^{-\frac{4}{13}t}+31.8825$$

$$\sum F_2=m\frac{dv_2}{dt}=mg-b_2v_2$$

$$\frac{dv_2}{dt}=g-\frac{b_2}{m}v_2;\frac{b_2}{m}=c_2=\frac{18}{13}$$

$$\int_{25}^{v}=\frac{dv}{g-c_2v_2}=\int_{0}^{t_2}dt\Rightarrow -\frac{ln(g-c_2v_2)}{c_2}+\frac{ln(g-25c_2)}{c_2}=t_2$$

$$v_2(t)=17.915e^{-\frac{18}{13} t}+7.085$$

From

$$x_2(t)=m\frac{d^2x_2}{dt^2}=mg-b_2\frac{dx_2}{dt}$$

I have

$$\frac{m(gt-v)}{b}+C=\frac{m(gt-(17.915e^{-\frac{18}{13}}+7.085))}{b}+C$$

Comment: Dont cross post; you will end up wasting peoples time; question was posted here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3998662/parachutist-and-differential-equations-modeling-air-reistance

Comment: @xXx_69_SWAG_69_xXx The only comment I got was to perhaps post here. I didn't just cross post for the hell of it..

Comment: its all good, just make sure to note that you asked it somewhere else too, just incase someone answers it one place, dont wanna waste someone elses time :)

Comment: Alright, I will keep that in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments and suggestions:

1. The time for parachute to open can be found by your Eq. $\ln\frac{g}{g-c_1 v_1} = c_1 t_1$ with $c_1 = 4/13$ when $v_1 = 25 m/s$.

$$
   t_{1f} = \frac{14}{3} \ln \frac{g}{g- \frac{3}{14} 25} \tag{1}
$$

2. Then your have to calculate the distance travelled before the parachute opened.

   The distance as function of time
   $$
      x_1(t) = x_{10} + \int_0^{t_{1f}} v_1(t) dt = x_{10} + \int_0^{t_{1f}} \{-31.8825 e^{-c_1 t} + 31.8825\} dt. \tag{2}
   $$

This integral can be done, not too difficult. $x_{10}$ may set to 0, and calculate time for $x_2$ to reach 2500 m. The $x_1(t_{1f})$ will be the initial position for $x_2$.

3. Similar, calculate the position $x_2(t)$ as function of time by integral (not differential equation.)

$$
   x_2(t_2) = x_{20} + \int_0^{t_2} v_2(t) dt = x_{20} + \int_0^{t_2} \{17.915 e^{-c_2 t} + 7.805\} dt. \tag{3}
$$
Where $x_{20} = x_1(t_{1f})$ continues from the position of $x_1$ at $t_{1f}$ in Eq.(2). This integral is same as that in Eq.(2) can be done.

Final step: set $x_2 = 2500$ in Eq.(3), we then find the final time $t_{2f}$. Your answer is $t_{1f} + t_{2f}$.

But in equation (3) with $x_2 = 2500$, the final time can only be solved numerically by Newton's method.